# How to Scroll the trackbar using speech recognition in c#

Tags: c#

Am working on a project to use speech recognition which my saying a number, will move the trackbar at the said value and when the trackbar is moved, it will control a servo. Apparently, When am trying to use speech to move it its not doing anything. Here's the code:

```
case "move right fifty":
niya.Speak("moving right 50 degree");
Val_trackBar.Focus();
Val_trackBar.Value.ToString("50");
break;

 private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (port.IsOpen)
        {
            port.WriteLine(Val_trackBar.Value.ToString());
            //lblDegree.Text = "Degree: " + Val_trackBar.Value.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not actually set the data to 50. You get the value - a reference to an int32, call the ToString("50") [method on the int](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8wch342y(v=vs.110).aspx) (which will try to convert the value according to your parameter).

Instead, set the value using this:

```
Val_trackBar.Value = 50;
```

And your scroll event would not fire, because according to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.trackbar.scroll(v=vs.110).aspx) Scroll "Occurs when either a mouse or keyboard action moves the scroll box.".

Instead, use the [ValueChanged-event.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.trackbar.valuechanged(v=vs.110).aspx)

So, you probably have a line like:

```
Val_trackBar.Scroll += trackBar1_Scroll;
```

Change that to:

```
Val_trackBar.ValueChanged += trackBar1_Scroll;
```